# formatting arrays php and separating them

Tags: php, arrays

i am receiving an array like this

```
[
    {"date":"2018-06-16","val":"no","amount":2},
    {"date":"2018-06-18","val":"no","amount":30},
    {"date":"2018-06-18","val":"yes","amount":2},
    {"date":"2018-06-19","val":"no","amount":26},
    {"date":"2018-06-19","val":"yes","amount":3},
    {"date":"2018-06-20","val":"yes","amount":4}
]
```

so what i want to do is to have a separate array `$date[]`  to only contain dates but should not be repeated which i have done using `array_unique()`so i have a array that looks like

```
 $date =  [2018-06-16,2018-06-18,2018-06-19,2018-06-20]
```

but as you can see not all date have a val of either `yes` or `no` 
so i want two arrays `$yes[]` and `$no[]` so if a date doesnt have the value yes or no it should be zero so final result will be like

```
$date =  [2018-06-16,2018-06-18,2018-06-19,2018-06-20]
$yes =[0,2,3,4]
$no = [2,30,26,0]
```

i hope my questions is clear

Comment: What you are receiving is a JSON, use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to make it into an array.

Comment: Please include the code you have so far

Comment: Where do you get the $yes values from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
$json = '[{"date":"2018-06-16","val":"no","amount":2},{"date":"2018-06-18","val":"no","amount":30},{"date":"2018-06-18","val":"yes","amount":2},{"date":"2018-06-19","val":"no","amount":26},{"date":"2018-06-19","val":"yes","amount":3},{"date":"2018-06-20","val":"yes","amount":4}]';

//Convert the json string into an associative array
$arr = json_decode($json, true);

//Get all unique dates
//Use array_column to convert the associative array into a simple array
//Use array_unique to get the unique values from the simple array
$date = array_unique(array_column($arr , "date"));

//Make a temp array to combine the date and val as the key. Use the amout as the value
$temp = array_reduce($arr, function($c, $v) {
    $c[ $v['date'] . '-' . $v['val'] ] = $v['amount'];
    return $c;
}, array());

//Just do a simple foreach to loop thru the $date
//Check if the key exist from the temp array using isset()
$yes = array();
$no = array();
foreach( $date as $val ) {
    if ( isset( $temp[ $val . '-yes' ] ) ) $yes[] = $temp[ $val . '-yes' ];
    else $yes[] = 0;

    if ( isset( $temp[ $val . '-no' ] ) ) $no[] = $temp[ $val . '-no' ];
    else $no[] = 0;
}
```

This will result to:

```
//$date
Array
(
    [0] => 2018-06-16
    [1] => 2018-06-18
    [3] => 2018-06-19
    [5] => 2018-06-20
)

//$yes
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)

//$no
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 30
    [2] => 26
    [3] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt would be using the [`array_map(…)`](http://php.net/array_map) function in combination with [`array_filter(…)`](http://php.net/array_filter) (assuming you already have unique dates in your array):

```
/** @var $receivedData list of received dates */

$dates = array_map(function(array $date) {
    return $date['date'];
}, $receivedData);

$yes = array_filter(array_map(function(array $date) {
    return $date['value'] == 'yes' ? $date['amount'] : null;
}, $receivedData);

$no = array_filter(array_map(function(array $date) {
    return $date['value'] == 'no' ? $date['amount'] : null;
}, $receivedData);
```

Please, be aware of the fact that if you don't pass a callback to `array_filter(…)` also zero values will be filtered. You could pass a function comparing `null` only to fix that.

Also, this is just a first shot. It is not optimized in the sense of performance. or anything like that. I guess it's better to just iterate the whole array once and push all items as needed to the previously defined arrays `$dates`, `$yes` and `$no`.